# Combining data tables

Tags: excel, indexing, vba

I have two data tables, similar to the ones below:

**table1**

```
index   value
a   6352
a   67
a   43
b   7765
b   53
c   243
c   7
c   543
```

**table 2**

```
index   value
a   425
a   6
b   532
b   125
b   89
b   664
c   314
```

I would like to combine the data in one table as in the table bellow using the index values. The order is important, so the first batch of values under one index in the common table must be from the table 1

```
index   value
a   6352
a   67
a   43
a   425
a   6
b   7765
b   53
b   532
b   125
b   89
b   664
c   243
c   7
c   543
c   314
```

I tried to do it using VBA but I'm sadly a complete novice and I was wondering if someone has any pointers how to approach to write the code?

Comment: To write the code, start by recording a macro.  You can combine the two tables, then use a stable sort algorithm on the Index column.  Probably the simplest to implement would be the range.sort (the worksheet built-in sort) of Excel. (A stable sort is one that retains the original order if two keys are equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the values of the second table (without the headers) under the values of the first table, select the two resultant columns and sort them by *index*.

Hope it works!